# In Google Sheets, is there a way to fill down a formula but have the formula adjust two cells at a time?

Tags: google-sheets

CORRECTION: starting cell is G2, not D1.

Example:

Formula in G2: =C2

If I drag the formula down, it will fill in:

```
G2: =C2
G3: =C3 
G4: =C4 
G5: =C5
```

etc.

Is it possible to drag this formula down so that the formula skips cells? So that the formula fills down like this:

```
G2: =C2
G3: =C4
G4: =C6
G5: =C8
```

etc

I've tried filling in the first few cells manually and highlighting 2+ cells so that the pattern will be recognized, but it ends up copying the highlighted cells instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
=offset($C$1,row()*2-1,)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your formula did work, but it starts pulling data from 2 lines further down than I want. It seems I made a mistake in my premise. I'm actually putting this formula into "D2" not "D1" because D1 has my header. So, when I put the indirect formula into D2 it pulls from C4 then C6 etc, which means I'm missing C2. Anyway to fix that? –

Comment: =offset($C$1,row()*2-3,) should work for that

Answer (score 0):

You may use this cell `D1` and drag it down:

```
=indirect("C"&row()*2)
```

or if you are tying to filter all the even rows data, you may also try

```
=filter(C:C,iseven(C:C))
```

[image]

Comment: The indirect formula did work, but it starts pulling data from 2 lines further down than I want. It seems I made a mistake in my premise. I'm actually putting this formula into "D2" not "D1" because D1 has my header. So, when I put the indirect formula into D2 it pulls from C4 then C6 etc, which means I'm missing C2. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: Try: `=indirect("C"&(row()-1)*2)`